# FB.api() method prevents returning true or false

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, asynchronous, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm breaking my brains for like 1,5 hour on this very little problem i've got.
Situation: File A -> request to File B, if file B returns true, user is registered and doesn't need to get added into our database. If false, user is signed into Facebook, but never logged in before -> add to database.

My problem: FB.api() prevents my function from returning true because of the async-call.

```
function registered(){
                FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                    $.ajax({
                    async: true,
                    url: "facebook-sdk/src/check.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {id: response.id},
                    success: function(data) {
                        if(data=='true'){
                            return true;
                        }else{
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    });
                });                    
}
```

And my call to the function:

```
 if(registered())
    alert('true');
 else
    register();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could change like:

```
function registered(callback){ //pass callback function as parameter
   FB.api('/me', function(response) {
       $.ajax({
          async: true,
          url: "facebook-sdk/src/check.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: {id: response.id},
          success: function(data) {
              callback(data);
          }
       });
    });                    
}
//call registered function
registered(function(response) { //callback function here
    if(response) { //if true is returned
      alert("Registered Already");
    }
    else {
      your_register_function();
    }
});
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood me a little bit. My question is, when i return true inside the if(data == 'true') it will return false when i call the function because of the async (FB.api()), how can I edit this function so it will return true?

Comment: @Jordy see my updated answer. do you mean something like that..?

Comment: Thanks for the help, slightly modified your code to got it working! Never knew about the callback option in Javascript. Could you explain your second function name? Got it working after editing the registered(function(response))